# Are there plans to support chrome.system.display API in a future version of Opera?

Tags: opera, opera-extension

I was planning to port over my chrome extension [Tab Resize](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tab-resize-split-screen-l/bkpenclhmiealbebdopglffmfdiilejc?hl=en-US) to Opera. I'm using the [chrome.system.display API](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tab-resize-split-screen-l/bkpenclhmiealbebdopglffmfdiilejc?hl=en-US) to get the user's display information in order to support multi-screen setups.

I wanted to check if there were plans to support the display API. It's the only thing hindering me from porting over the extension.

Thanks,
Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will implement the API in Opera 30.